# How to optimize the sum of two scikit-learn models together

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

Say I have a some feature vectors [x1, x2] mapped to a scalar property y. I could use scikit-learn to fit a given model and make predictions. So I assume

```
f([x1, x2]) —> y
```

Then I can call model.fit(**X**,**Y**), model.predict(**X**,**Y**), and so on.

I could also separate the components of the feature vectors and just assume two separate functions were additive

```
f(x1) + f(x2) —> y
```

So now I have two machine learning models, which give predictions for different features, the sum of which I assume maps to my property. What would be the best way to optimize both models together?